# How do I preload values into a Select2 control and still search remote data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

When I preload values into Select2 dropdown, and expand the control to type in a value. It filters the preloaded values. How do I configure Select2 to make ajax calls (new search) when I type in the text box? If I don't preload values into Select2, the ajax calls work. So how can I have both?

I preload my select2 control with something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: url,
    data: json,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data.d);
        var arrData = [];
        if (json !== null && json !== undefined) {
            if (json.length > 0) {
                $.each(json, function (index, element) {
                    var item = { id: element.CommonName, text: element.CommonName, name: element.CommonName };
                    arrData.push(item);
                });
            }
        }
        $("[ID$=ddlDropDown]").select2({
            data: arrData
        });
    }
});
```

I instantiate my Select2 control with this:

```
$("[ID$=ddlDropDown]").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        delay: 500,
        data: function (params) {

                var query = {
                    searchString: (params.term || ""),
                    page: params.page
                }
                // Query paramters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
                return JSON.stringify(query);


        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data.d);
            if (json != null) {
                if (json.length > 0) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(json, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.CommonName,
                                name: item.CommonName,
                                id: item.CommonName
                            }
                        })
                    };
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        },
        success: function (data, page) {
            $("[ID$=ddlDropDown]").select2("data", data, true);
        }
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: "Select a Value",
    disabled: false,
    cache: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

as i had this problem and could not found any solution, I would like to share a solution which i did.even this is an old question which is not answered yet.would be helpful for others

```
      $('#select2').select2({
            allowClear: true,
            multiple: false,
      //    minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: "url",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                type: 'POST',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, container) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.title + '| <b>' + item.title_2 + '</b>',
                                id:  item.id,
                            }
                        })
                    };
                },
                cache: false
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                return markup;
            },
            placeholder: __('select.project_search'),
        }).live('change', function (e) {
           // on change code
         });
```

And in your controller you can check
if search term is null then return the preload options
else run the SQL for search data or return remote data.

> the trick is you have to comment out minimumInputLength

this will trigger select2 ajax whenever you click it. and loads preload for you like following

[image]

and when you search you will get remote results like this
[image]

I hope this will help someone searching for a solution